# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to log service exceptions servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I'm getting the following message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When trying to log the exceptions thrown by the service, I'm using the following service exception handler in my ApphostBase

```
ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add((httpReq, request, exception) => {
    Logger.Error(exception);
    return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, exception);
});
```

The exception is thrown by ServiceStack.dll

```
at ServiceStack.DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(Object request, Exception ex)
   at MyApp.<>c.<Configure>b__3_16(IRequest httpReq, Object request, Exception exception) in C:\Users\Company\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyApp\src\MyApp\MyApp\AppHost.cs:line 175
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.OnServiceException(IRequest httpReq, Object request, Exception ex)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.HandleException(IRequest request, TRequest requestDto, Exception ex)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Process(IRequest requestContext, Object instance, Object request)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceExec`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, Object requestDto, String requestName)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRequestExec`2.Execute(IRequest requestContext, Object instance, Object request)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.<>c__DisplayClass37_1.<RegisterServiceExecutor>b__1(IRequest reqCtx, Object requestDto)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.ManagedServiceExec(ServiceExecFn serviceExec, IService service, IRequest request, Object requestDto)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.<>c__DisplayClass37_0.<RegisterServiceExecutor>b__0(IRequest req, Object dto)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.Execute(Object requestDto, IRequest req)
   at ServiceStack.HostContext.ExecuteService(Object request, IRequest httpReq)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.GetResponse(IRequest request, Object requestDto)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)
```

The line 175 is:

```
return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, exception);
```

Both request and exception have values. I'm am running an mvc application and also consuming the api handled by ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory. I'm using ServiceStack v4.5

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was a [NullReferenceException issue resolved in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/9bd68715360b5fb18aa56b4491733c8ecc50dc74#diff-f14d6e1a8ce59d6b02d1368756d2a630) which is available from the latest v4.5.4 release of ServiceStack.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even with the framework upgrade to version 4.5.4

Comment: @HerberVásquez ok, but I can't tell what the issue is from here (e.g. we have tests showing [CreateErrorResponse() working in ServiceExceptionHandlers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/f13104ffa1156f543f67ad4e27fdb3070c297e0f/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/CacheResponseTests.cs#L209)). If you can put together a small stand-alone project that shows the issue (e.g. in a Github repo), we'll be able to identify and resolve the issue.